# Erro ao efetuar cálculo de média

Tags: c#, .net

Gostaria de pegar a soma de todos os salários e dividir pela quantidade de funcionários, mas esta dando erro, quando compilo diz que esta com 0 nas variáveis `Count` da lista e total.

```
public class Informacao
{
    public float salBruto { get; set; }
    public int numFilhos { get; set; }
}
class Ex2
{
    List<Informacao> info = new List<Informacao>();
    public void CadNovaPesquisa()
    {
        Informacao infoo = new Informacao();

        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine("Informe seu salário bruto:");
        infoo.salBruto = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Informe a quantidade de filhos:");
        infoo.numFilhos = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        info.Add(infoo);
    }
    public void CalculaMedia()
    {
        int i = info.Count;
        float total;
        total = info.Sum(x => x.salBruto);
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        //float media = total / i;
        Console.WriteLine($"TOTAL: {total}");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Nem tentei ver o erro já que tem outros problemas no código, escrevendo da forma correta funciona, ainda que eu mudaria várias outras coisas:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program {
    private static List<Informacao> informacoes = new List<Informacao>();
    public static void Main() {
        CadNovaPesquisa();
        CadNovaPesquisa();
        CalculaMedia();
    }
    public static void CadNovaPesquisa()   {
        var informacao = new Informacao();
        WriteLine("Informe seu salário bruto:");
        if (!decimal.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var salBruto)) return;
        informacao.SalBruto = salBruto;
        WriteLine("Informe a quantidade de filhos:");
        if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var numFilhos)) return;
        informacao.NumFilhos = numFilhos;
        informacoes.Add(informacao);
    }
    public static void CalculaMedia() {
        var total = informacoes.Sum(x => x.SalBruto);
        WriteLine($"TOTAL: {total} MEDIA: {total/informacoes.Count}");
    }
}

public class Informacao {
    public decimal SalBruto { get; set; }
    public int NumFilhos { get; set; }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/gUeQwn). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aABy9m). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Typing/ToDecimal.cs).